# Ubuntu 15.10. Rhythmbox + last.fm = Token expired

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.10, rhythmbox, authentication

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and Rhythmbox. The problem is that I can't login to last.fm. The program always gives an error  saying "Token expired".

I upgraded Rhythmbox (to 3.3) and its plugins from the ppa but there was no result. I tried to set a different default browser but again with no  result.

Up to this point I haven't got any clue how to solve this. Can anybody help me?

Some images of process are below.

## 1. Open last.fm in player

[image: Open last.fm in player]

## 2. Press log in

[image: Press log in]

## 3.This page opens

[image: auth page]

## 4. Pressing "Yes" and getting the same error

[image: Token error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue until recently. What you should do is delete the contents of `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/audioscrobbler`, particularly the file `sessions`, then try and authenticate again. It should work then.